# How to prefetch Wagtail post tags?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have around 10 posts and it is generating about 100 queries to fetch post tags.  The `taggit` library Wagtail used underneath [support`prefetch_related`](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/tests/tests.py#L608), but adding `prefetch_related` has no effect. After more research, I found that the culprit is Wagtail's `ClusterTaggableManager` that overrides `taggit`'s `TaggableManager`.

In the [changelog](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt), it says

```
2.0 (22.04.2016)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    
* Fix: prefetch_related on a ClusterTaggableManager no longer fails (but doesn't prefetch either)
```

It has been 2 years and it seems they are not going to fix it anytime soon. So... Is there anything I can do to reduce the number of queries? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @allcaps You can find their demo here. It has the same problem. [Demo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/blog/models.py#L74)